# ajaxCRUD : two questions about insert

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I start to play with [ajaxCRUD](http://ajaxcrud.com/) which seems to be simple but effective class.
I have a table users like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_users (
  usr_id        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  usr_name      VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  usr_surname   VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  usr_pwd       VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
  usr_level     INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY ( usr_id )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
  $tblUsers->omitPrimaryKey();

  $tblUsers->displayAs("usr_name", "Nome");
  $tblUsers->displayAs("usr_surname", "Cognome");
  $tblUsers->displayAs("usr_pwd", "Password");
  $tblUsers->displayAs("usr_level", "Livello");
  $tblUsers->omitField("usr_pwd");

  $tblUsers->modifyFieldWithClass("usr_pwd", "password");

  $allowable_vals = array(1 => "USER", 2 => "ADMIN", 3 => "SUPERUSER");

  $tblUsers->defineAllowableValues("usr_level", $allowable_vals);
  $tblUsers->formatFieldWithFunction('usr_level', 'make_usr_level');
  $tblUsers->onAddExecuteCallBackFunction("AddCallBack");

  $tblUsers->addButtonToRow("Dettagli", "UserDetails.php");
  $tblUsers->addButtonToRow("Collega case", "HousesList.php"); 

  $tblUsers->setLimit(30);

  #my self-defined functions used for formatFieldWithFunction
  function make_usr_level($val){
    return FAUser::LevelToString($val);
  }  

  function AddCallBack($array)
  { 
    //these indexes are the fields of the db
    $success = qr("INSERT INTO tbl_users 
                    ( usr_id, 
                      usr_name, 
                      usr_surname, 
                      usr_pwd, 
                      usr_level )
                   VALUES (NULL, 
                           '" . $array[usr_name] . "', 
                           '" . $array[usr_surname] . "', 
                           AES_ENCRYPT('" . $array[usr_pwd] . "', 
                                       SHA2('FonteAlma_2013', 512)), 
                           " . $array[usr_level] . ");");
  }

  #actually show to the table
  $tblUsers->showTable();

?>
```

The table is displayed correctly and shows the already inserted users but, when I add a new user, I get:

```
4 - TheGivenName - TheGivenSurname - [BLOB - 7 B] - 0
```

So the password and the user level are not set well.

Also, when I edit the level field into the table, which is a combobox containing the three levels, I always get 0 whatever value I chose.

Where I wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I code my solution.

Maybe this is not the best/right solution...but seems to work.

I added a method onBeforeAddExecuteCallBackFunction() which is called before executing the ADD query.
If this callback returns FALSE the execution ends (the function doAction returns). otherwise continues.

This is the diff file:

```
263d262
<   var $onBeforeAddExecuteCallBackFunction;
352d350
<     $this->onBeforeAddExecuteCallBackFunction   = '';
653,657d650
<   function onBeforeAddExecuteCallBackFunction($function_name){
<     $this->onBeforeAddExecuteCallBackFunction = $function_name;
<     $this->ajax_add = false;
<   }
< 
900,906d892
<         // Added
<         if ($this->onBeforeAddExecuteCallBackFunction != '') {
<           // If the Callback return FALSE, I quit
<           if (!call_user_func($this->onBeforeAddExecuteCallBackFunction, $submitted_array))
<           return;
<         }
<
```